# Wait Until Current Location is set in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions

Tags: iphone, core-location, uiapplicationdelegate

My Home UIView requires current Location coordinates and I wouldn't want it to be called until I have these coordinates. How best can I achieve this?

in this code, the view is called before the update of current location:

```
 - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

        currentLocation = [[CLLocation alloc] init];
    locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    locationManager.delegate = self;
    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

TTNavigator *navigator = [TTNavigator navigator];
            navigator.persistenceMode = TTNavigatorPersistenceModeAll;
            TTURLMap *map = navigator.URLMap;

            [map from:@"tt://HomeView" toViewController:  viewController];
            [navigator openURLAction:[TTURLAction actionWithURLPath:@"tt://HomeView"]];
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

users can have Location service turned off. so I wouldn't do that..
Instead check for the location after the didFinishLaunchingWithOptions, so that your current problem will be solved.
and add one more screen for user to turn on the location service if it's off.

Comment: Without the Location service, the app is useless.

Comment: Yes, I get that.. didFinishLaunchingWithOptions is not good place to check that.. if user don't allow to use location service your app will never open. at least display some message to let user know.